# Opencv in ROS: fatal error: opencv3/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: ros, opencv, ros-kinetic, opencv3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*EDITED:*

Hello,

I just started using opencv with ROS and I am trying to to write a program using the default opencv3, which comes with ROS Kinetic.
I have the following inclusions in my .cpp file:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv3/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv3/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv3/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

the following package.xml:

```
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>cv_bridge</build_depend>
  <build_depend>image_transport</build_depend>
  <build_depend>image_geometry</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>opencv3</build_depend>
  <run_depend>sensor_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>cv_bridge</run_depend>
  <run_depend>image_transport</run_depend>
  <run_depend>image_geometry</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>opencv3</run_depend>
```

and the following CMakeLists.txt file:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
    project(kinect_vision)
    
    ## Find catkin macros and libraries
    ## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
    ## is used, also find other catkin packages
    find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
      sensor_msgs
      std_msgs
      cv_bridge
      image_transport
      image_geometry
      roscpp
    )

   find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED) ##I also tried it without REQUIRED

    catkin_package(
      INCLUDE_DIRS include
    #  LIBRARIES kinect_vision
      CATKIN_DEPENDS cv_bridge image_transport image_geometry roscpp
      DEPENDS OpenCV
    )
    
    include_directories(
      ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )
    
    
     add_executable(kinect_vision_node src/kinect_vision_node.cpp)
    
    
     target_link_libraries(kinect_vision_node
       ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
     )
```

I get the following errors while trying to catkin_make my workspace:

```
/home/legged/vision_ws/src/kinect_vision/src/kinect_vision_node.cpp:5:30: fatal error: opencv3/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
kinect_vision/CMakeFiles/kinect_vision_node.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'kinect_vision/CMakeFiles/kinect_vision_node.dir/src/kinect_vision_node.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [kinect_vision/CMakeFiles/kinect_vision_node.dir/src/kinect_vision_node.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:385: recipe for target 'kinect_vision/CMakeFiles/kinect_vision_node.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [kinect_vision/CMakeFiles/kinect_vision_node.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Any ideas how can I fix this?

Thanks for your answers and for your time in advance,

Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245024/opencv-in-ros:-fatal-error:-opencv3/opencv.hpp:-no-such-file-or-directory-compilation-terminated./) by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Chris,

As the error indications, your compiler cannot find OpenCV. You are probably missing some things in your CMakeLists.txt, do you require openCV?

> find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

There is some information on how to use OpenCV3 on the wiki located [here](http://wiki.ros.org/opencv3) it links to the transition guide that can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html), which explains that the layout of the header files has changed a little but in any case they are still under opencv2 for backwards compatibility. Update the headers to opencv2 and check if it affects the modules in your include and update those as well.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-10-05**:
I edited my question after your suggestion according to the example's package.xml and CMakeLists.txt. The issue still remains.

**Comment by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) on 2016-10-05**:
Reading the OpenCV [transition guide](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html) it seems that the header locations are under opencv2 instead of opencv3 for backwards compatibility. If you update the includes to the right location the compiler *should* be able to find them.

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-10-05**:
I will test it tomorrow at the lab's computer. Thank you for the suggestion again, I hope it will work.

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-10-06**:
Thanks a lot rbbg. Your comment made the error disappear and a sample code, I used, worked. Try to edit your answer so I can accept it :)

Thanks again,

Chris

**Comment by [matwilso](https://answers.ros.org/users/27246/matwilso/) on 2017-06-19**:
@patrchri, can you post the header code and CMakeLists.txt that you eventually got to work?